Не работают запросы в vue в nginx
Есть вот такой код
const urls = {
  login: "/auth/v1/auth/login",
  refreshToken: "/auth/v1/auth/refresh",
  validate: "/auth/v1/auth/validate",
  change_pwd: "/auth/v1/auth/change-password",
};

и
const urls = {
   users: "/auth/v1/user",
   roles: "/auth/v1/role",
};

и вот сам nginx.conf
location /auth/ {
  proxy_pass  https://$AUTH_URL/api/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_intercept_errors  off;
  proxy_buffer_size       4k;
  proxy_buffers           4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  proxy_read_timeout 120;
  proxy_connect_timeout 120;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
}

location /api/ {
  proxy_pass  https://$BACKEND_URL/api/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_intercept_errors  off;
  proxy_buffer_size       4k;
  proxy_buffers           4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  proxy_read_timeout 120;
  proxy_connect_timeout 120;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
}

Проблема - запросы на users и roles не работают, хотя запросы авторизации, валидации и т.д все работает, но если поменять вместо auth на api то все работает, но уже не работают методы proxy_pass  https://$BACKEND_URL/api/; если я у них location заменю на что то другое вместо api
у меня он почему то перенаправляет на location /api/ хотя должен на location /auth/

Что такое $AUTH_URL и $BACKEND_URL? Почему в location /auth/ в proxy_pass написано .../api/ ?

на $AUTH_URL и $BACKEND_URL не обращайте внимание, там лежит url бэкенда, а .../api/ это https://бэкенд/api/
